# knitr Czech diacritis in chunk end up in wrong UTF8 char

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, latex, knitr

When knit()ting the following document called `dia.Rnw`on Windows only the diacritic characters in chunks (blocks) are printed incorrectly. Printing them inline with `\Sexpr{}` works as expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

<<c1>>=
sCaron <-  "\u0161"
@

Priting the diacritic character \Sexpr{sCaron} inline with \verb|Sexpr{sCaron}| results in 
the correct UTF-8 character in the .tex document.

Using a chunk/block (output is wrapped in a verbatim environment) does not print the right 
character.
<<c2>>=
sCaron
@


\end{document}
```

The file is saved as UTF-8, knitr (version 1.11) is invoked with

```
knit("dia.Rnw", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

My `sessionInfo()`:

**R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)**

**Platform:** x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

**Running under:** Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

**locale:**
LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252,  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252, LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252, LC_NUMERIC=C,  LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252

**attached base packages:**
stats, graphics, grDevices, utils, datasets, methods, base

**other attached packages:**
knitr_1.11, devtools_1.9.1.9000

**loaded via a namespace (and not attached):**
magrittr_1.5, formatR_1.2.1, tools_3.2.2, memoise_0.2.1, stringi_0.5-5, highr_0.5.1, stringr_1.0.0, digest_0.6.8, evaluate_0.8, fortunes_1.5-2

Comment: I don't see any details here about locale setting or fonts.

Comment: What is your `sessionInfo()`? Please add that to your post.

Comment: @Yihui, sorry for doing it this late. Due to holidays in Austria, I didn't have access to the machine.

Comment: No worries. This sounds like a bug of knitr. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: I spent quite a few hours on this problem, and it seems to be really hard to fix. I think the problem comes from the evaluate package (specifically, the `textConnection()` and `sink()` in https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/blob/master/R/watcher.r). I'm running out of ideas now. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for investigating it, I'm going to watch it. For the time being I will knit the file using Linux.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Everything works as expected here. Please describe specifically what goes wrong for you.